# How to initialize attributes calculated from other attributes in python classes

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I have an attribute in a class that I want to calculate from other attributes.

I want this attribute to be private, so I would like to make it a property.

I understand that a property still needs to be called in the **init** block of the class, however i didn't find an elegant way to write that.

Some ugly code that does what I need:

```py
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, t=0):
        self.attrA = t
        self._attrB = None

    @property
    def attrB(self):
        return self._attrB

    @attrB.setter
    def attrB(self, value):
        self._attrB = 2*self.attrA

obj = ABC(10)
print(obj.attrB)
```

Question: how can I avoid declaring attrB in **init** with a dummy 'None' value?

Edit to previous post:

- Ideally I would like attrB to really be a 'stored' attribute (not just a property getter), so that it is not recalculated every time it is called: in my usecase attrA and attrB are long lists so recalculating attrB each time it is called is a no-go
- I understand caching the property call is also an option, but is there not a simpler way by having a real attribute?

Comment: As a side note, `ABC` is not a good name for a class, even in a quick example because of `abc` module and `abc.ABC`... Even 'A` is better.

Comment: makes sense will remember that:)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a `self._attrB` at all, *or* an `attrB.setter`, since your `attrB` getter can return whatever you want the value of `attrB` to be (in this case it's twice the value of `attrA`):

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, t=0):
        self.attrA = t

    @property
    def attrB(self):
        return 2 * self.attrA

obj = ABC(10)
print(obj.attrB)
```

A good clue that your `attrB` setter was unnecessary is that it ignored the `value` that you passed to it!  It's simpler to just put this logic in the getter since it's not dependent on any data that isn't already stored in the class.

(edit) If the logic you use to generate `attrB` is more complicated, you could cache it like this:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class ABC:
    def __init__(self, t=0):
        self.attrA = t

    @property
    def attrB(self):
        return self._attrB(self.attrA)

    @lru_cache
    def _attrB(self, attrA):
        return 2 * self.attrA
```

The `@lru_cache` will cache the return value of `_attrB` based on the value of `attrA`, so it will recompute if `attrA` has changed, and otherwise serve up the value from the cache.

If you don't want `attrB` to change when `attrA` changes, then you can simply use `cached_property`, which computes the value the first time you access it and thereafter uses a cached copy:

```
from functools import cached_property

class ABC:
    def __init__(self, t=0):
        self.attrA = t

    @cached_property
    def attrB(self):
        return 2 * self.attrA
```

and obviously if you don't want `attrA` itself to change after it's initialized, you can make it a private variable.

Comment: Thanks I thought about that, i.e. just using a property getter, however in that case is attrB going to be cached, or is it going to be recalculated everytime we call obj.attrB?

Comment: In my use case these attributes are list that can be long, I would want to have to recompute attrB more than once

Comment: With that implementation, it's recalculated each time, but there's no reason you couldn't do caching in the getter.  I bet you could even just use `@functools.lru_cache` instead of having to actually implement your own cache.  :)

Comment: Ok thanks, if the standard approach is to use a property as a getter + do the caching then that works for me, just wanted to check if there was another way

Comment: You could also have some other method that does the recalculation, but doing it in a setter with a bogus argument is a bad pattern IMO because it's generally implied that if you do an assignment, the property takes the value of whatever you assigned, rather than ignoring it and taking some other value.  You'd want it to just be a parameter-less method called `refresh_attr()` or something like that.

Comment: Added a couple of examples to the answer with `lru_cache` and `cached_property`.

Answer (score 0):

About the edited part of your post:

An `atrrB` property *is an attribute*. By making it a property, you just add code that runs when this attribute is accessed for read or write, or both.

A property is one of the possible types of a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=properties)

Caching an expensive calculation of a property is a good solution.

If you are starting with Python, descriptors is an advanced feature. However using properties or even caching is quite straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, updated to 'stored' attribute to clarify. If there is no easier solution than caching the property result then fine i will do that. Indeed from what I have read on Descriptors there might be other ways using __setattrt__ explicity but I will keep the simpler approach for now